# Changes to be made to make the given code more effecient

Tags: java

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/csindia/challenges/pin-problem-1

The below solution for above problem is not getting submitted, "timeout terminated" message was popping out. For successful submission what changes should be made below code? Please help me out.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int testcase = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if (testcase > 0 && testcase <= 100000)
            {
                int outarr[] = new int[testcase];
                for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
                {
                    String str = br.readLine();
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    if (n > 0 && n <= 10000 && m > 0 && m <= 10)
                    {
                        int maincounter = 0;
                        str = br.readLine();
                        String s[];
                        s = str.split(" ");
                        if (s.length == m)
                        {
                            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                            {
                                int counter = 0;
                                for (int l = 0; l < s.length; l++)
                                {
                                    if (k % (Integer.parseInt(s[l])) == 0)
                                    counter++;
                                }
                                if (counter == s.length)
                                    maincounter++;
                            }
                            outarr[i] = maincounter;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter the specified values of m not more than that");
                            testcase--;
                        }   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter value of n in between 1 to 10^4 and value of m in between 0 to 10");
                        testcase--;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < testcase-1; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(+outarr[i]);
                }
                System.out.print(+outarr[testcase-1]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the test value in between 1 to 10^5");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ae)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add what you've tried and why they've failed before we can help you.

Comment: Well, according to the page you're supposed to put it in a method with return type int called main(). Maybe that's part of the problem? edit: never mind - didn't realize it was another language XD

Comment: I have attached the link of the problem. Below that i have posted my solution for that problem but at the time of submission "execution terminated due to timeout" message was popping up and the problem was not getting submitted. So what changes shall i make to improve the above code? That's what i am asking!

Comment: Have you tried writing JUnit tests for your code and running it locally? That might provide better errors for you.

Comment: Sherling you mean to say that i should make use of functions in order to make it more optimal?

Comment: What is JUnit tests? I am completely unaware of it.

Comment: They are tests that you can write to test parts of your Java code. Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or are you just using the editor in hackerrank?

Comment: For future reference, questions like this are much better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary checks in your code that are slowing it down a little, but honestly not enough to make it not finish. Hackerrank tells you what the bounds will be for the input, so you don't need to verify it for these purposes.

I've gone through the code and added comments for you where this could be improved:

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int testcase = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

```
        // This check is unnecessary, hackerrank told you testcase would be in these
        // bounds.
        if (testcase > 0 && testcase <= 100000)
        {
            int outarr[] = new int[testcase];
            for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
            {
                String str = br.readLine();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
                int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int m = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

                // This check is unnecessary, hackerrank told you m and n would be in these
                // bounds.
                if (n > 0 && n <= 10000 && m > 0 && m <= 10)
                {
                    int maincounter = 0;
                    str = br.readLine();
                    String s[];
                    s = str.split(" ");

                    // This check is unnecessary, hackerrank told you the next line
                    // would have m numbers
                    if (s.length == m)
                    {
                        for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                        {
                            int counter = 0;
                            for (int l = 0; l < s.length; l++)
                            {
                                // Here, instead of checking every number to see
                                // if it is divisible, you can check and see if 
                                // it isn't. If it isn't, then you shouldn't bother
                                // checking the rest of the possible numbers because
                                // you know that k isn't a possible pin number.
                                // Add a flag that indicates if the pin is still valid,
                                // if it isn't, move on to the next pin.
                                if (k % (Integer.parseInt(s[l])) == 0)
                                counter++;
                            }
                            if (counter == s.length)
                                maincounter++;
                        }
                        outarr[i] = maincounter;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter the specified values of m not more than that");
                        testcase--;
                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter value of n in between 1 to 10^4 and value of m in between 0 to 10");
                    testcase--;
                }
            }

            // Why the -1? You can just do i < testcase and print it all here
            // instead of on multiple lines.
            for (int i = 0; i < testcase-1; i++)
            {

                System.out.println(+outarr[i]);
            }
            System.out.print(+outarr[testcase-1]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the test value in between 1 to 10^5");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ae)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
}
```

Code after changes:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    try{
        BufferedReader br = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int testcase = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int outarr[] = new int[testcase];
        for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
        {
            String str = br.readLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int m = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int maincounter = 0;
            str = br.readLine();
            String[] s = str.split(" ");
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
            {
                boolean stillValid = true;
                for (int l = 0; l < m && stillValid; l++)
                {
                    if (k % (Integer.parseInt(s[l])) != 0)
                    {
                        stillValid = false;
                    }
                }
                if (stillValid)
                {
                    maincounter++;
                }
            }
            outarr[i] = maincounter;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(outarr[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ae)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught " + ae.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mdewitt for improving my code . Suggestions suggested by you will be very much helpful for me in future programming contests. Thanking you once again .